# File read write not working with multiple datatypes

Tags: c

I have a program in C language in which I want to store multiple dataype values in a file and read the same from the file. The following code writes data into file but stores the data in unreadable form. Also when I fetch that data, I get garbage values.

I am using Codeblocks 17.x

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
   char name[100];
   int maths, hindi;
   char gend;
};

int main()
{
   struct student num[3];
   struct student num1;
   int i;
   FILE *fptr;
   if ((fptr = fopen("studlist.txt","w")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);
   }

   for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter your name: ");
      gets(num[i].name);
      printf("Enter Marks in Maths: ");
      scanf("%d", &num[i].maths);
      printf("Enter Marks in Hindi: ");
      scanf("%d", &num[i].hindi);
      printf("Enter Gender (M/F) ");
      fflush(stdin);
      num[i].gend=getchar();
      fflush(stdin);
      fputs("Student ", fptr);
      putw(i, fptr);
      fwrite(&num[i], sizeof(struct student), 1, fptr);
      fputs("\n",fptr);
   }
   fclose(fptr);
   if ((fptr = fopen("studlist.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);
   }

   for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
   {
      printf("Student %d: ",i);
      fread(&num1, sizeof(struct student), 1, fptr);
      printf("%s | Maths: %d\tHindi: %d\tGender: %c\n", num1.name, num1.maths, num1.hindi, num1.gend);
   }
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
}
```

**Data stored in the file:**

[image: Data stored in the file]

**Data shown as a result of read operation:**

[image: Data Shown as a result of read operation]

Also, I am not able to implement the search and update code. For example, if I want to update the marks of Jenny, I am not able to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you expect a file containing binary values to be readable as text? Also you have written other values to file besides the `struct` but not read them back.

Comment: Please only tag languages your question is actually about. You said C, so tag it only as C and only C.

Comment: You want to read about [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) first ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your **writing** and **reading** are **asymmetrical**.

You write each `student` record like this:

```
  fputs("Student ", fptr); /**/
  putw(i, fptr);           /**/
  fwrite(&num[i], sizeof(struct student), 1, fptr);
  fputs("\n",fptr);        /**/
```

and then you read each `student` record like this:

```
  fread(&num1, sizeof(struct student), 1, fptr);
```

Just get rid of the extra writes (the lines I marked with asterisks) and it should work.

Comment: There is a problem with the non-standard `fflush(stdin)` and a better way should be found to get rid of unwanted newlines in the input, perhaps with `scanf(" %c", &num[i].gend);` (note the leading space).